# Set property type based on reflection of another object

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

Lets say I have two classes:

```
public class IntKeyObject{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     [ForeignKey]
     public int ForeignKey {get;set;}
     public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
     ...
}
public class StringKeyObject{
     public string Id {get;set;}
     [ForeignKey]
     public string ForeignKey {get;set;}
     public string SomeOtherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to be able to make an container class as such:

```
public class ObjectViewModel<T>{
     public [the type of the objects key] ForeignKey {get;set;}
     public IEnumerable<T> MyList {get;set;}
}
```

where I initialize it like below:

```
new ObjectViewModel<IntKeyObject>();
```

Is there a way to use reflection on the object type to set my ForeignKey property type?
Right now the only way I know how to do it is by explicitly passing in the Key type like so:

```
new ObjectViewModel<IntKeyObject, int>();
new ObjectViewModel<StringKeyObject, string>();
```

I would prefer to set that type by inference.  I know how to find the correct property type from a class by getting the attribute, what I'm not sure about is how to set up my container class.

Comment: Generics must be known at compile-time, reflection runs at run-time. So, short answer, no, you cannot infer what you don't know

Comment: Let's say you create this object using reflection, how would you then expect to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the property needs to be knows at compile time.

```
 public [the type of the objects key] ForeignKey {get;set;}
```

Setting `[the type of the objects key]` not at compile time is not possible.

However, you can have some options:

1. use 'object'
2. Create multiple types and use a factory that will check what the type of the key is and use that.
3. Use string for all `ObjectViewModel` objects - stringify the int key

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure if it was possible but had to be sure!